# Developing Apps using Adobe PhoneGap on Ubuntu OS

Tags: adobe

Hi I would like to know if its possible to develop app using HTML, CSS, Javascript and PhoneGap SDK on a Ubuntu system and uploading the app on to Adobe PhoneGap Build for packaging it into native installation files for iOS,Android and windows.

All I see on the official Adobe PhoneGap guide is, its support for OS's like Mac and Windows only.

I know I could use cordova on Ubuntu, But i need to use Adobe PhoneGap Build for packaging the app.

Comment: I can't seem to be able to answer, but yes you can. Just use `npm install -g phonegap` .

Comment: It is possible to run in under Linux systems without any hassle. Just check the documentation at http://docs.phonegap.com/getting-started/1-install-phonegap/cli/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adobe usually doesn't release their applications for Linux platform. So, what you see is correct, Adobe PhoneGap is only for Windows and Mac. If you must use the PhoneGap, you should seriously consider OS other than Linux.

You may also try installing it in WINE. But WINE doesn't work well with latest versions of softwares. So, there is no guarantee that it will be helpful.